# Spring-boot oauth2 /oauth/token 404

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

- so I have an existing SpringBoot project.

a) I added this at the top of my main @Configuration class

```
@Import({ WebSecurityConfiguration.class, OAuth2ServerConfiguration.class })
```

b) The contents of the above 2 classes are the same as what is in this project: https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth/tree/master/src/main/java/hello

c) I startup my app and see this as expected in the logs:

```
2015-10-28 20:05:40,037 INFO [FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal) 
2015-10-28 20:05:40,037 INFO [FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal) 
2015-10-28 20:05:40,040 INFO [FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException 
2015-10-28 20:05:40,040 INFO [FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException 
2015-10-28 20:05:40,041 INFO [FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] Mapped "{[/oauth/check_token]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint.checkToken(java.lang.String) 
2015-10-28 20:05:40,041 INFO [FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception 
2015-10-28 20:05:40,042 INFO [FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping] Mapped "{[/oauth/error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelErrorEndpoint.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

d) When I go to /greeting I get the following as expected:

```
{ "error": "unauthorized", "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource" }
```

e) When I attempt to POST to /oauth/token I see the below in the logs... but I get a 404 and no token back. This has been driving me nuts now for 2 days trying to figure this out. Any help appreciated.

```
2015-10-28 20:08:59,713 DEBUG [FilterSecurityInterceptor] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [fullyAuthenticated]
2015-10-28 20:08:59,713 DEBUG [FilterSecurityInterceptor] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7159411d: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@8e81ee76: Username: clientapp; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: USER
2015-10-28 20:08:59,713 DEBUG [AffirmativeBased] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@44aef1f8, returned: 1
2015-10-28 20:08:59,713 DEBUG [FilterSecurityInterceptor] Authorization successful
2015-10-28 20:08:59,713 DEBUG [FilterSecurityInterceptor] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2015-10-28 20:08:59,713 DEBUG [FilterChainProxy] /oauth/token reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2015-10-28 20:08:59,714 DEBUG [ExceptionTranslationFilter] Chain processed normally
2015-10-28 20:08:59,714 DEBUG [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Again, I just get a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in my main @Configuration annotated class I had a dispatcherServlet @Bean registered, which was intercepting all the requests. Once I changed the method name to something other than dispatcherServlet() it fixed the issue:

BAD:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, "/x/*");
}
```

GOOD:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean thisFixedMyIssue() {
    CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, "/x/*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not adding Authorization in the header.Without adding header you cannot access the resources, and sometimes it shows error of Bad Credentials.For postman  POST call for /oauth/token at there authorization is needed in header.

If i am not adding any authorization to the header.It shows me following error:-
{

```
"error": "unauthorized",

"error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
```

}

You can create Authorization with the help of [Base64Encoder](http://www.base64encode.org)